# Android Bluetooth Java, Constant bluetooth stream to fill up array and write to sdcard

Tags: java, android, arrays, bluetooth, buffer

I am writing an Android app that uses bluetooth to stream data (bytes) into an array in another class. The idea behind this is to record a set amount of data (i.e. buffer[60000]) and when it is full, write the buffer to a file and store it on the SD Card.

The issue i am having is everytime the call is made on the bluetooth class and it handles a method of HandleBluetooth.write(buffer, bytes); to send to the HandleBluetooth class my buffer index is getting reset each time that pass is made. The index for the buffer, and the buffer are both global variables which is confusing me as to why it is setting the index back to 0 every time HandleBluetooth.write(buffer, bytes); is called so i am never able to fill the buffer to write it to the file.

here is my code:
BluetoothSerialService.java

```
        public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[9999];
        int bytes;

        // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                HandleBluetooth.write(buffer, bytes);
                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                //mHandler.obtainMessage(BlueTerm.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();

                String a = buffer.toString();
                a = "";
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                connectionLost();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

HandleBluetooth class:

```
        public static void write(byte[] buffer, int length) {
        byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) buffer;
        data_length = length;
        for (x = 0; x < data_length; x++) {
            raw = UByte(readBuf[x]);

            if (odd_even_flag == 0) {
                buffer1[out_index] = raw;
                // System.out.println("ch1: " + buffer1[out_index]);
                odd_even_flag = 1;

            } else {
                buffer2[out_index] = raw;
                // System.out.println("ch2: " + buffer2[out_index]);
                odd_even_flag = 0;

            }
            if (x % 10000 == 0) {
                Write2File(buffer1, buffer2);
            }
            out_index++;
            if (x >= 60000) {
                StopIncomingData();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see I have been trying to index the buffer using out_index which is a global class variable.

I feel like this is something dumb that i am over looking here. Please steer me in the right direction so i can understand why my index is being reset every time that method is called.